# I unable to return Async function variable to caller function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

// this function will recieve array of two sets, containing youtube url and which will in turn call youtube oembed api and receive iframe and video properties, everything was working i am able to receive data from youtube api and convert into them array, but i am unable to pass to the caller function

```
 function getWaterfall(data){
        var resultArr = [];
         function iter(datas, callback){    
        async.waterfall([
           function getData(callback){
           var link = nconf.get('youtubeuri')+encodeURIComponent(datas.src);
           console.log(link);
             http.get(link, function(res) {
            console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
            res.on("data", function(chunk) {                   
                var result = JSON.parse(chunk);
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                 callback(null, result)
                 });
        }).on('error', function(e) {
              callback(err);
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
          })  
        },
        function processData(results,callback){
            var sets = {};
              sets.videotitle = results.title;
              sets.videothumb_url= results.thumburl;
              sets.videoiframe= results.html;
              sets.videoheight= results.height;
              sets.videowidth= results.width;
              sets.videoauthor= results.author_name;
              sets.videoauthurl= results.author_url;
              callback(null,sets);                
            },
            function updateArray(resu, callback){
                 resultArr.push(resu);
                 console.log(resu);
                 callback(null);                    
         }
       ],
      function finalcall(){            
             console.log('operation completed');
             console.log(resultArr.length);
             console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArr));
             callback(null);    
         });         
  }
 async.each(data, iter, function(){                 
         console.log('array completed');
         console.log(resultArr.length);
         return resultArr;            
         console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArr));                    
    });       
 }
 // caller function 
  exports.uploadPaletteVideo = function(req,res){  
       Palette.findById(req.body.palid, function(err, videodoc){
              if(err){
               util.log('palette with id not found video '+err);
            }else{               
 var mar = [{'src':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k98k47X_Ugo'},    {'src':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OLsmfxalPw'}];
            console.log('the palette' + getWaterfall(mar));               
            //console.log('From PaletteVideo'+ JSON.stringify(youtube));              
           }                            
    }) 
 res.send('success');
}
```

my code unable to return array to caller function, but i am able to pass this array to another function and its working. please help me out..

Comment: You can't return an asynchronous result from a function, you have to provide it to the caller via callback.

Comment: Obviously because asynchronous means that your calling function doesn't sit there waiting for the return, but moves on.

Comment: if you want to return something, return a promise:  https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: yep done, thank you very much, actually I miss that...